# matlab find line interception and represent it

Tags: matlab, line, intercept

For this given example:

```
a=rand(100,1)
ecdf(a)
```

The obtained plot will have on x proportion of bin values, and on y the proportion of points. I wanted to add a line y=0.5 (50% percent of values) and when cross the line in the plot gather and shows the predicted x value.

It is possible but it suppresses my knowledge.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I interpret your question correctly - but could it be as simple as

```
a=rand(100,1)
ecdf(a)
hold on
plot([0 1],[1 1]*0.5);
```

This adds a line at a height of 0.5 from `0` to `1` (which I believe are the limits of the plot that `ecdf` produced for you).

If you want to find the point where these two lines intersect, you need to obtain the points in the plot using a different form of the `ecdf` function:

```
a = rand(100,1)
[f x] = ecdf(a);
figure
plot(x, f); % now you have to make the plot yourself...
hold all
plot(x, 0.5 * ones(size(x))); % add the line at y=0.5
title 'cumulative probability of rand()'
xest = interp1(f, x, 0.5); % interpolate - find x where f would be 0.5
fprintf(1, 'The intercept is at x=%.2f\n", xest);
```